# use left join in LINQ method synthax

Tags: vb.net, linq, left-join

I have two tables: `t1` and `t3` and I have following sql query:

```
select t1.*, t3.* from t1 left join t3 on t1.f1=t3.f1
```

`t1` contains 30k records, `t3` has only 10. The matching field is `f1`.

`t1` has 5 fields, `t3` has 2 fields.

With the above query I get the 30k records + 10 field values also like this:

```
t1.f1, t1.f2, t1.f3, t1.f4, t1.f5, t3.f1, t3.f2
```

The records are so, that there is a matching only in case of the first 10 records. So after that, `t3.f1` and `t3.f2` are empty values.

Now, I would like to write a query in LINQ, wich produces this result:

```
Dim JoinedResult = LeftTable.GroupJoin(RightTable, Function(LeftTableRow) LeftTableRow(FieldIndexInLeftTable), _
                                                             Function(RightTableRow) RightTableRow(FieldIndexInRightTable), _
                                                             Function(LeftTableRow, RightTableRow) New With {LeftTableRow, RightTableRow.DefaultIfEmpty(Function(Item) IIf(Item Is Nothing, Nothing, Item))})
```

As you see, I'm trying to tell LINQ, that if any item of the RightTableRow is empty, then I need the field value in this case too, with an empty value.

But vb says: Anonymous type member name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments.

It is important, that the fields of table `t3` can be various, so defining an empty value for `t3.f1` and `t3.f2` is not an option. I need to define an empty value (null) for all fields in `t3`, if there is no matching record.

It can be, that in `t3` there is more matching record to a row in `t1`, so I must use SelectMany too, but how?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
Dim JoinedResult = LeftTable.GroupJoin(RightTable, Function(LeftTableRow) LeftTableRow(FieldIndexInLeftTable), _
                                     Function(RightTableRow) RightTableRow(FieldIndexInRightTable), _
                                     Function(LeftTableRow, RightTableRow) _
                                     New With {LeftTableRow, RightTableRow}). _
                                     SelectMany(Function(Row) _
                                     Row.RightTableRow.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(Function(RightT) _
                                                                                  New With {Row.LeftTableRow, _
                                                                                            Key .rt = RightT.Select(Function(Item) IIf(Item Is Nothing, String.Empty, Item)).ToArray}))
```

with this the error message disappear, but I get a null exception at runtime, which is obv. results from the fact, that RighT is - except the first 10 records - null.

Comment: This is a common question - the answer is to use a GroupJoin combined with DefaultIfEmpty() See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq NB - this was found with a simple search

Comment: Yes, this is a common question, but a bit different. In each examples the right table has a fix column number and so it's easy to test the fields of null value. But in my case, the right table may have x columns, in another case y columns. With the edited code (see edit), I don't have the error message anyomore, but I get a nullexception (source cannot be null).

Comment: So add a check `IIf(RightT Is Nothing, ...`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

Your code should look to follow :

```
var query =
   from left in LeftTable
   join right in RightTable on right.FieldIndexInRightTable equals  left.FieldIndexInLeftTable
    into gj
    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {Your fields };
```